# Find all solutions $x^2=1(mod 143)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I have the following question:

Find all solutions $x^2=1(mod 143)$

**This is what I did :**

11,13 are prime therefore :

$$(1)\space x^2=1(mod 11)$$
$$(2) \space x^2=1(mod 13)$$

using The Chinese Theorem I get that :

$$x^2=(11*x_1*1)+(13*x_2*1)$$

Finding $x_1,x_2$

$13x_1=1(mod 11) \rightarrow x_1=6+11k$

$11x_1=1(mod 13) \rightarrow x_2=6+11k$

Therefore : $$x^2=(11*x_1*1)+(13*x_2*1)=x^2=(11*6*1)+(13*6*1)=144+143k$$

But wolframalpha finds $4$ different solutions and I just found one, Any ideas what I did wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i have got $$1,12,131,142$$ as the solutions

Comment: $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ is equivalent to $x \equiv \text{plus or minus } 1 \pmod{11}$. Same for mod 13.

Comment: You found one solution for $x^2$, and that's all there is, but the question wants you to find all solutions for $x$, and there are four of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are *two* solutions to $x^2 \equiv 1\pmod{11}$, namely $1$ and $-1\equiv 10$. The same thing goes for $13$. Therefore, the Chinese remainder theorem gives you *four* solutions to the entire problem, namely:
$$
\cases{x\equiv 1\pmod {11}\\x\equiv 1\pmod{13}}\\
\cases{x\equiv 10\pmod {11}\\x\equiv 1\pmod{13}}\\
\cases{x\equiv 1\pmod {11}\\x\equiv 12\pmod{13}}\\
\cases{x\equiv 10\pmod {11}\\x\equiv 12\pmod{13}}\\
$$

Comment: So generally speaking when I want to use the Chinese Theorem I need to get rid of the powers in order to use it?

Comment: @JaVaPG No, the CRT doesn't care about that. Quadratic equations have multiple solutions (or none) in modular arithmetic, just as they do for the regular integers / ratioanls / reals / complex numbers, and you forgot to take that into account.